# How to make earth progress pie

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, progress-bar

I would want to add to my website a progress bar with this design:

[The progress pie](https://www.instagram.com/p/CBk8zdanjL4/)

How do I make a progress pie with an image inside it, and when it moves it display the image inside it with colors?

Comment: Please visit the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) . Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is non-trivial but could be achieved by using two images, `clip-path` and a script, a greyscale image and a coloured image.

1. Position the greyscale image under the coloured one.
2. Use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to only show a portion of the coloured image.
3. Adjust the clip-path values using a JavaScript loop OR using a css key-frames animation

## Here's a simplified keyframes example:

```css
.greyscale {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.color {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: clippy 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes clippy {
  0%    { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0,  50% 0,  50%    0,  50%    0,  50%    0,  50%    0); }
  12.5% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100%    0, 100%    0, 100%    0, 100%    0); }
  25%   { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100%  50%, 100%  50%, 100%  50%); }
  37.5% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%); }  
  50%   { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,  50% 100%,  50% 100%,  50% 100%); }
  62.5% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,    0 100%,   0  100%,    0 100%); }  
  75%   { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,    0 100%,   0   50%,    0  50%); }  
  87.5% { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,    0 100%,   0     0,    0    0); }
  100%  { clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,    0 100%,   0     0,  50%    0); }
}

div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;  
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="greyscale" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg">
  <img class="color" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg">
</div>
```